# data couldn’t .... isn’t in the correct format

Tags: ios, swift, parse-server

I have the following code in a Swift iOS app using `Parse-Server`.

```
func theWiftFunction() {
    PFCloud.callFunction(inBackground: "myCloudFunction",
                         withParameters: ["unitID": somePFObject.value(forKey: "objectId")!,
                                          "userID": (PFUser.current()?.objectId)!]) {
                                            (object: Any?, error: Error?) in
                                            if error != nil {
                                                if error?.localizedDescription == "NO-UNIT"
                                                {print("The given unit has not been found for this user. This should not happen.")}
                                                else {print("Error in \(#function)\n" + (error?.localizedDescription)!)}
                                                return
                                            }
                                            // All is OK!!
                                          };
    .......
}
```

It partially works fine, but in some cases I get this error message:

```
Error in theWiftFunction()
The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.
```

The question is: Why is the data, sometime in the correct format, sometime not ? What should I do to get "the correct format" ?

Comment: Did you check the issue in the parse-server github? https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server/issues/717

Comment: Yes I read the post but did not think I could use it to find a solution.